# In what sort of lands could I install my people?

Tags: deserts, farming

Here is the plot: in a society close to earth and humans, but with medieval-like technologies, there is a group of people that is regularly migrated to a new place where it should installed itself. This group can bring material and tools but in the end, it should work by itself with the resources of the new land. The group could have any size between 5 000 to 20 000 people in it, the size will depends of what is possible to do.

So this looks like rather easy migration, but here are the problems:

- The group will go in an uninhabited area: it will have to build everything from scratch
- The group will go to "non-nice" areas: in the plot, "nice lands" with temperate climate are already occupied. What we called desert (either sand, mountain, snow... deserts) is the targeted zone for the migration
- The group will have to build some sort of sustainable system (not just take the few resources in the new region and then move again)

Now the advantages:

- All social and economic organization are allowed
- If everyone is focused on getting something to eat, then it is ok. The group is not supposed to build cities and medieval comfort fastly

--------- EDIT ---------

Some precisions about the plot:

- The polar desert could be either Antarctic or Arctic style
- The medieval group could have some modern "permanent" technologies. For example he knows about phones but have none, and he could be vaccinated (but could not take medicine with him)
- The group only needs to survive there, and not to have enough means to re-build a civilization

My story's plot would be that the group is sent to a region similar to Arctic (or Antarctic). But how could I justify this region to be appropriate, especially about the capability to have a reliable and durable of source for feeding this group?

**Final question:** How could a group of 5 to 20 thousand medieval colonists go to and establish themselves in a previously unpopulated polar desert and survive by their own means?

Comment: Note that 1 million people is a lot in medieval times, even more so when migrating in a foreign and "non-nice" lands

Comment: The whole reason deserts are considered "non-nice" in the first place is that it's difficult or impossible to maintain a population there. If it were possible for a large group to live on that land, people would already be doing so.

Comment: @Tortliena Yes you're right, 10 000 is a better number for my plot

Comment: VTC:Needs Details or Clarity. I can't see how you can choose a best answer based on the information you've provided. What research have you performed? With the exception of a spot in Africa and ignoring Antarctica, humans have colonized just about every square inch of Earth. That includes every biome you mentioned and a great many more. And I don't know what "easier" means. Is every foot along every river, lake, or ocean already taken? Is every tree-bearing spot gone? Humanity has set up shop in very inhospitable places and thrived.

Comment: VTC: Needs details or clarity. Five thousand people is one thing, they can survive on a relatively small island by fishing, for example; one million people is quite another thing: the entire population of England in 1066 was about 2 million people. Migrating to a desert implies an mass epidemic of insanity, nobody did that ever in the entire history of mankind. Migrating into the mountains is different from migrating into colder areas. (And I don't get what you mean by snow being "not nice". Snow is a normal regular phenomenon throughout most of northern, central and eastern Europe.)

Comment: Answering VTC @JBH : Best answer will be chosen on the behalf of arguments given for the advantage of a location by the answerers. The exception of man installation are very numerous: sand deserts in Africa, South Chile, Mongolia, jungles in SA and Asia, ice/snow deserts in north and south poles... Some humans live in these biomes but they are definitely not implanting a massive human occupation

Comment: Answering VTC @AlexP: I edited for the size of the group. The migration is not a point I had thought about, but it could be considered as secondary for the purpose of the plot (and anyway I don't understand how it justifies VTC). Snow falls are common but snow desert (better to say ice desert, I admit) are inhospitable)

Comment: @totalMongot Thanks for the clarification about biomes (note, always [edit] your post with clarifications. Never assume anyone will read the comments). However, after years of experience on the site, I know "arguments given for the advantage..." won't (and doesn't) work. Stack Exchange's model expects a specific problem to be solved. E.G., "I want to move my people to the African savanah and have the following skills What resources should be available?" It's specifically not a discussion forum (see [tour]) or useful for open brainstorming (see [help/on-topic]). (*\Continued\*)

Comment: ... Why is this important? Because we can rationalize almost any location you want for your story, which means your story's reasons for wanting someone somewhere are more important than the factual issues involving the location. Tell us where you want to go and we'll help you get there. Ask us where you should go and we'll VTC: Needs More Details (or Too Story-Based, take your pick).

Comment: @JBH I understand the reasoning behind the VTC, and I'll edit accordingly.
Still, I would like to highlight that I want to know the most logical situation in a given situation. I should build my story as a logical thing.

Comment: @totalMongot if I understand correctly, the question is now "What sort of area in a previously unpopulated polar desert would a group of 5 to 20 thousand medieval colonists be able to establish a self-sustaining civilization?"  Is that correct?

Comment: The problem is the phrase "the most logical situation" is subjective (opinion/story-based). Stack Exchange avoids subjective questions. You're expected to select a best answer. If you understand logic and the needs of your question well enough to judge "the most logical situation," then why do you need to ask the question? SE's sweet spot (in terms of [worldbuilding.se]) is "here's the solution I want, how can I get there?" not "what's the best solution?" Any time you're tempted to use words like best, worst, most, least, etc. in your question, there's a 90% chance it's not ready to be asked.

Comment: @JBH I guess we're not supposed to debate of it there but.... You say "best" is one of the no-go words and at the same time I'm supposed to choose the "best answer". This is evidently a contradiction: if I can judge of proposed ways to go in polar desert, why couldn't I judge of proposed ways to go in a desert and compare to the way to go to polar desert?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 The area needed is interesting but the question is more: is it possible and if yes how?
I'll finish the edit byt the question would be: "How could a group of 5 to 20 thousand medieval colonists go to and establish themselves in a previously unpopulated polar desert and survive by their own means?". The plot is not about establishing a civilization but just barely survive

Comment: @totalMongot If you read the [help], the concept behind a "best answer" is identified. It's based on the fact that what Stack Exchange wants (and that's who you're fighting against, not me) is *objective questions.* An objective question always has a right/best/most-appropriate answer. Subjective questions don't. In the case of superlatives, the problem is you are ***required*** to define them. "Best" when it comes to questions is usually circumstantial (opinion-based) or, worse, only reflected by something in your head that we don't know. If you think this is wrong, try [meta.se].

Comment: Yes I perfectly understand the problem of subjective vs objective question. But asking "what [desert in my case] fits best X and Y criteria [reliable source of feed for medieval population]" is objective. Here "best" is just a word and not something I define in my head. What I define in my head is X and Y and I gave them explicitly. Anyway I'll consider asking on Meta

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that they can take shelter with them in the form of tents, the overriding issue will be finding enough food. If they enter a desert area they will fairly rapidly exhaust whatever provisions they could bring and the limited provisions that might be found in the new locality and they would all starve.

The best best would be to follow a coastline where at least there might be the option of fishing or to follow a river upstream, even if the vegetation to either side was limited (gallery forest or similar) this would provide more sustenance and the river would provide the possibility of irrigation.

If the intention is to go into a true desert area then the supplies taken should be extensive, the group size small (one million would die very quickly) and there should be some target site for development such as an oasis.

In most cases your medieval travellers would simply starve or die of thirst or heat/cold. Even in temperate areas it is easy to starve if you are unfamiliar with the local vegetation as many Europeans did in North America when they first arrived.

Answer (score 1):

The 'dark ages' are more commonly known as 'The Age of Migrations". Many people just upped sticks and moved, assuming the grass was greener on the other side. A proper historian may be able to fill you in a bit, but I am not sure even they know 'why'. Does everyone shifting around a bit meet your criteria?